# Database Backup from SQL Server to Blob Container losing connection at 24 minute time

Tags: sql-server, azure-blob-storage

From SQL Server 2014, I am using a saved Credential to my Azure File Storage.  For a small database, using BACKUP DATABASE command, the backup was successful to the Azure storage container.  Fora large database, over 6TB, I expected the backup to take quite a while.  However, once the backup reaches a few seconds short of 24 minutes, it errors with the following error message (* values are hidden for security).

> Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE [Sup_********_249243_13dec19] 
>   TO..." failed with the following error: "Write on
>   "https://***storageaccountname***.blob.core.windows.net/dbdumps/Sup_********_249243_13dec19_backup_2019_12_26_125220_1290224.bak"
>   failed: 1117(The request could not be performed because of an I/O
>   device error.)

SQL Command (items hidden for security):

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Sup_********_249243_13dec19] 
TO  URL = N'https://***storageaccountname***.blob.core.windows.net/dbdumps/Sup_********_249243_13dec19_backup_2019_12_26_125220_1290224.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'Sup_********_249243_13dec19_backup_2019_12_26_125220_1290224', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
GO
```

While the job is running, I see the file in the storage container, with active Lease.  However, I cannot see where I can change the default Lease time.

Answer (score 1):

Answer (to be tested) found at:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url-best-practices-and-troubleshooting?view=sql-server-ver15

Consider COMPRESSION, MAXTRANSFERSIZE, BLOCKSIZE and multiple URL arguments when backing up large databases. See Backing up a VLDB to Azure Blob Storage (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2017/03/10/backing-up-a-vldb-to-azure-blob-storage/)